# How to resolve unable to decode stream error in android?

Tags: android, json

I am getting file not found error when trying to fetch image and text from remote server
Error :-

```
E/BitmapFactory(888): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/localhost/galerie/albums/userpics/10001/Water_lilies.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-03 11:06:15.159: E/BitmapFactory(888): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/localhost/galerie/albums/userpics/10001/thumb_1ce5b4759c0062faafc4a7c84c02fa99.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Json output of url is :-

```
{"cpg15x_pictures":[{"title":"Flowers","path":"http:\/\/localhost\/galerie\/albums\/userpics\/10001\/Water_lilies.jpg"},{"title":"Building","path":"http:\/\/localhost\/galerie\/albums\/userpics\/10001\/thumb_1ce5b4759c0062faafc4a7c84c02fa99.jpg"},{"title":"Test","path":"http:\/\/localhost\/galerie\/albums\/userpics\/10001\/Sunset.jpg"},{"title":"Food","path":"http:\/\/localhost\/galerie\/albums\/userpics\/10001\/f1.jpeg"}]}
```

I am trying to populate the list view which contains two components image view and text view. When I run the program,it populates the list with text but images are not populated.
Instead logcat is populated with error.

I referred other related questions on stackoverflow to resolve this error but I am able to fix this problem.

Reference http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html

What can be the solution ?

Comment: Link generated from JSON seems to be incorrect. Notice the single / after http:..   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/localhost/galerie/albums/userpics/10001/Water_lilies.jpg

Comment: I guess the error is also because of single / before http but how to fix this @akashsr

Comment: parsing/escaping the single / will work ?

Comment: Are you doing any operations on the (path) string ?

Comment: Yes. I was was doing it wrong. You pointed the error correctly. I removed that extra sing / and error got fixed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed that extra sing / and error got fixed